# Queries to check condition within a table - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Need queries to check below condition

```
SNO CLEANPRODUCT CLEANID
100 ABC          1 
100 ABC          1
100 XYZ          2

101 DEF          3 
101 DEF          3
101 AAA          4
```

Within a SNO each CLEANPRODUCT should have same CLEANID.

Comment: What if it doesn't have the same id? What do you want as output?

Comment: Running below query select a.sno,b.sno from table a,table b where a.cleanproduct=b.cleanproduct and a.cleanid!=b.cleanid group by a.sno,b.sno limit 1; If above query returns value, it means it fails the logic as the table has different id for same clean product within a SNO; if this query didn't anything it means my condtions (table data) is fine.

Comment: Can someone confirm if the above posted query is fine to test this condtion??

Comment: If you had another row SNO = 101, CleanProduct = ABC, CLEANID = 5, this would show in the query you have above, but I think it would be OK by the rules you set. You need to add a.sno = b.sno to the where clause